# "The name 'Request' does not exist in the current context"

Tags: razor, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

EDIT: I have now changed `Request` to `Context.Request` and am receiving a different error to the title of this post now: `Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'HttpRequest'`

So I am trying to introduce myself to ASP.Net and am following an online tutorial available here: https://www.w3schools.com/asp/webpages_forms.asp (the 'Displaying Images' part).  I am attempting to implement this in an MVC style layout.  The starting template for the structure is a modified version of the template that is produced when you run `dotnet new -t web`.

In my Pictures.cshtml file, I have the following:

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Pictures";

    var imagePath="";
    if (Request["Choice"] != null) 
    {
       imagePath="images/" + Request["Choice"];
    }
}

<h2>Pictures</h2>

<form method="post" action="">
    I want to see:
    <select name="Choice">
    <option value="Photo1.jpg">Photo 1</option>
    <option value="Photo2.jpg">Photo 2</option>
    <option value="Photo3.jpg">Photo 3</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    @if (imagePath != "")
    {
        <p>
        <img src="@imagePath" alt="Sample" />
        </p>
    }
</form>
```

This is called from a MainController.cs as so:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace WebApp.Controllers
{
    public class MainController : Controller
    {
        public IActionResult Pictures()
        {
             return View();
        }
    }
}
```

There is also a _ViewStart.cshtml which references a _Layout.cshtml.

When running this, I am redirected to my error page, and the terminal gives the error `The name 'Request' does not exist in the current context`

Can somebody help point me in the right direction as to what I am missing or what I have done wrong?  Why does this tutorial example not work in the context of my project?

Cheers :)

Comment: You have no element named "Choice". Try renaming your select to "Choice".

Comment: Oops, that indeed was a mistake!  However, it still isn't working - the errors are occurring before that point (the two lines that have the keyword 'Request' in them).

Comment: which mvc version do you use? Is it recognizing the Request object? Try Context.Request for .Net Core

Comment: It is .Net Core, I've only just realised today that they are 2 distinct frameworks!  I gave Context.Request a shot and now I'm getting `Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'HttpRequest'`

Comment: one last try ;) Context.Request.Form["Choice"]

Comment: New error again! `Operator '!=' is ambiguous on operands of type 'StringValues' and '<null>'`

Comment: I am really not sure if it will work, but try !String.IsNullOrEmpty(Context.Request.Form["Choice"])

Answer (score 6):

I had the same error in Core 2.1. I've found if you put it in the `ViewData` or `Styles` section, it's hard to debug (or something just wonky about it). Otherwise, it should work like this for a specific parameter:

```
@Context.Request.Query["Choice"]
```

For your code, I would just request the value once and assign it to a variable, then see if it's empty or not. Then, create the path from your variable:

```
var choice = @Context.Request.Query["Choice"];
var imagePath="";
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(choice)){
   imagePath="images/" + choice;
}
```

As a bonus, you can also get the entire query string with all the names and values (in case you want to parse it or whatever) by going:

```
@Context.Request.QueryString
```

Answer (score 4):

I use this in ASP Core 5.0 :

```
ViewContext.HttpContext.Request.Query["Choice"]
```

example in JS:

```
if (getParameterByName("error") != null) {
   window.location.href = "@Url.Action("Login", "Home" , new { error = ViewContext.HttpContext.Request.Query["Choice"] })";
}
```